# Finding the cipher suite used by a server using WinHTTP c++

Tags: winhttp

The current task I've been working on is to obtain the cipher suites that is currently used by a server.

I have been using WinHTTP and I haven't found anything related to cipher suites in this library.

Is there any way to do this? Just need to know whether it is possible through C++

Comment: Since you deleted your other question, I will comment here, since you are using `WINHTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT_POLICY_ALWAYS` flag, it will by default follow all the redirects from 301/302 status.

Comment: O M G, I realised. Thats why I felt it was a waste to ask. I'm sorry for wasting your time. And this is so amazing :D The way you found my older posts. Kudos mate!